# Is there a way discard previous pdfmark metadata?

Tags: pdf, pdf-generation, postscript

I was trying to automate adding title, bookmarks and such to some PDFs I need. The way I came up with was to create a simple `pdfmark` script like this:

```
% pdfmark.ps
[ /Title (My document)
  /Author(Me)
  /DOCINFO pdfmark

[ /Title (First chapter)
  /Page 1
  /OUT pdfmark
```

Then generate a new PDF with ghostscript using:

```
gs -q -dNOPAUSE -dBATCH -sDEVICE=pdfwrite -sOutputFile=out.pdf in.pdf pdfmark.ps
```

If `in.pdf` doesn't have any `pdfmark` data it works fine, however if it does things don't work out nicely: for example title/author aren't modified and bookmarks are appended instead of replaced.

Since I don't want to mess around modifying the PDF's corresponding postscript, I was trying to find if there is some command to add to `pdfmark.ps` that can delete (or overwrite) previous metadata.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'll leave PostScript to others and show how to remove a PDF outline using the [qpdf](http://qpdf.sourceforge.net) package (for `qpdf` and `fix-qdf`) and GNU `sed`.

From the `qpdf` manual:

> In QDF mode, qpdf creates PDF files in what we call QDF form.
> A PDF file in QDF form, sometimes called a QDF file, is a completely
> valid PDF file that has `%QDF-1.0` as its third line (after the pdf
> header and binary characters) and has certain other characteristics.
> The purpose of QDF form is to make it possible to edit PDF files,
> with some restrictions, in an ordinary text editor.

(For a non-GNU/Linux system adapt the commands below.)

```shell
qpdf --qdf --compress-streams=n --decode-level=generalized \
     --object-streams=disable -- in.pdf - |
sed --binary \
    -e '/^[ ][ ]*\/Outlines [0-9][0-9]* [0-9] R/ s/[1-9]/0/g' |
fix-qdf > tmp.qdf
qpdf --coalesce-contents --compression-level=9 \
     --object-streams=generate -- tmp.qdf out.pdf
```

where:

- 1st `qpdf` command converts the PDF file to QDF form for editing
- `sed` orphans outlines in the QDF file by rooting them at non-existing `obj` 0
- `fix-qdf` repairs the QDF after editing
- 2nd `qpdf` converts and compresses QDF to PDF
- `qpdf` input cannot be pipelined, it needs to `seek`

The `sed` command changes digits to zeros in the line containing
the indented text `/Outlines`.
Note that GNU `sed` is used for the non-standard `--binary` option
to avoid mishaps on an OS distinguishing between text and binary files.
Similarly, to strip annotations replace `/Outlines` with `/Annots` in
the `-e` above, or insert it in a second `-e` option to do both.
Another patch utility than `sed` will do; often just one byte has
to be changed.

To quickly strip all non-page data (docinfo, outlines a.o. but not
annotations) `qpdf`'s `--empty` option may be useful:

```shell
qpdf --coalesce-contents --compression-level=9 \
     --object-streams=generate \
     --empty --pages in.pdf 1-z -- out.pdf
```